# Deployment failed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by User without allow-window popping up

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

normally when I use live debugging on my android (xiamo mi 8) there appears a pop up window that asks if I want to install the application. This doesnt happen anymore and Visual Studio (I use Xamarin) gives me this:

> Fehler        ADB0010:  Deployment failed
> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Failure
> [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user]    bei
> Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String
> output, String packageName) in
> E:\A_work\548\s\External\androidtools\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:Zeile
> 341.

Noteable that I dont have a drive labeled with E. What I've tried:

- Disabled USB-debugging and enabled it again
- Revoked the debugging-authorisation for all known devices
- Disabled USB-install and enabled it again
- Restarted Windows PC and the phone

Answer (score 2):

Go to your **Developer options** and click on **Revoke USB debugging authorizations** and try again.

Also in Redmi devices, you might see a notification inside the notification list, just click on it and choose allow. This notification appears when you try to install the application via usb/adb